# Facing Issues with Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, file, save

Hi my name is Donald Jhon we have a community of Freelancers doing data entry jobs in various Microsoft products for this we have created a local area network with a central shared space to save the files. from last few days we are facing some issues while saving excel files over shared space the file says 'someone else is working on the file " but in reality the file is not opened by anyone else. i am attaching screen shot of the error so that someone may help me.

good day.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=someone+else+is+working+in+excel&sxsrf=APq-WBsAhsulJmSmyK6ibuv9GqISfE8m6g:1648976522649&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqi4CfxPf2AhXjgv0HHcmDCOgQ_AUoAnoECAEQBA&biw=1366&bih=625&dpr=1#imgrc=NZ1p9QA9f_MipM

Comment: Show the error in the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thanks for reply. the issue arise when anyone tries to save the file the error says "some one else is working on file" the same is discussed in this https://forum.sircles.net/posts/t1270-Excel-Error--Someone-else-is-working-on--filepath--right-now--Please-try-again-later